# Phonegap iOS Google Maps Return "for development Purpose only" Error

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, phonegap, google-geocoding-api

I'm complete my billing but the google map shows popup"this page can't load google maps correctly..." and "for development purpose only".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Enable** the **Maps JavaScript API** under APIs in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

Add API Key in your Map Url.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your-API-Key=false"></script>
```

[Refer this Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

any Error comes to refer this link:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages